# Making a program in c++ that will produce a triangle with stars, but the result is always 2 numbers off

Tags: c++

I am currently making a program that outputs a little triangle made off of stars (or asterisks) in c++, and I am facing some problems.

It seems as though whenever I write something to the function, the compiler interprets it as that number, minus two - something I find very strange.

```
int makePyramid(int len=1) {
    // A pyramid (or triangle) can not consist of less than 1 length.
    if(len < 1) {
        cout << "does not make sense" << endl;
    }
    else {
        // Go through the length
        for(int i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
            // Make one star for each number in the last loop
            for(int j = 1; j < i; ++j) {
                cout << "*";
            }
            // Makes a new line after the second loop is through
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the function in question. As you can see, it should work - the first loop goes through the whole number and then goes to the next loop which prints one asterisks depending on the value of the number, and then it outputs a new line so it can get started on the next set of asterisks.

Keep in mind that I am pretty new to C++, and I am using minGW in cmd (Windows 10) to compile the code.

Comment: Why do you start i and j from 1 and not from 0?

Comment: **Try something simpler.** Print a row, not a whole pyramid. When that doesn't work, try printing numbers. When that doesn't work, look carefully at your `for` loop, and fix it.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I really can't recall why I started with 1. I think it had something to do with the fact that I thought it would print an empty space, for some bizzare reason. I do know that computers count from the 0th index, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The loop `for (int i = 1; i < len; i++)` iterates `len - 1` times. `i` have values in the range of `[1; len - 1]`.

2) The loop `for (int j = 1; j < i; ++j)` iterates `j - 1` times. `j` have values in the range of `[1; i - 1]`.

That's why these function prints less asteriks. C style loops are tricky and are more powerful in comparison to, for example, Pascal loops. In order to fix that you need by initializing `i` and `j` with `0` or by replacing `<` with `<=`:

```
int makePyramid(int len=1) {
    // A pyramid (or triangle) can not consist of less than 1 length.
    if(len < 1) {
        cout << "does not make sense" << endl;
    }
    else {
        // Go through the length
        for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            // Make one star for each number in the last loop
            for(int j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
                cout << "*";
            }
            // Makes a new line after the second loop is through
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this not enough, second loop would print n-1 asterisks.

Comment: Thank you so, so much! I have only programmed in C# and some higher-level languages (I have fiddled with js, python, ruby and so on), but I feel more comfortable with lower level programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

First loop you should either start from 0 or change condition to <=

```
for( int i = 0; i < len; ++i )
```

or this

```
for( int i = 1; i <= len; ++i )
```

Though first one is more usual for C++ as commonly used to iterate over array indexes (from 0 to N-1). In your case it is irrelevant.

In the second loop you have to change condition to `<=` and start from the same number as i, so either:

```
 for( int i = 0; i < len; ++i )
     for( int j = 0; j <= i; ++j )
```

or

```
 for( int i = 1; i <= len; ++i )
     for( int j = 1; j <= i; ++j )
```